# Find the distance usuing hyperbolic metric between the point 2 + 4i and the hyperbolic geodesic with ideal endpoints -2, 2?

Tags: geometry

having trouble with this one since im not sure how to take the distance of a specific point and a geodesic, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Find the semicircle in the upper half plane (with diameter on the real axis, of course) passing through $2+4i$ and meeting the semicircle perpendicular to the real axis at $\pm 2$ orthogonally.

Comment: im afraid im still not getting it, sorry, english isnt my first language

Comment: You want a hyperbolic geodesic through $4+2i$ that intersects the given hyperbolic geodesic (with ideal endpoints $\pm 2$) orthogonally (with a right angle). Use geometry and algebra to find this. Then you'll use this geodesic to find the distance.

Comment: i think I see what im looking for, but i still cant seem to find out where exactly to go from here?

Comment: Draw pictures and use basic geometry facts and algebra. You're looking for the *center* $(a,0)$ of that semicircle.

Comment: I've found that a = sqrt(21), am I correct? What do I do from here? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that $a=6$. Once you have the geodesic (semicircle), you should have a formula (in terms of angles) for the distance between two points on that curve.